# Linking 1 VSTS instance to multiple Azure Subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have **1 VSTS** instance, which is currently linked to **1 Azure Subscription**. Now we have two Azure subscriptions:

1. One for Production applications.
2. One for Sandbox applications, where we develop applications.

Now I want to setup a **develop** CI build that links to our Sandbox and another **master** build for production releases to our Production subscriptions.

So I have two subscriptions linked to my Azure AD account:

[image: My Subscriptions]

When I look in my **Team Services accounts** in Azure its only linked to the Production account:

[image: TS Area]

Can I link one VSTS instance to multiple Azure subscriptions that my account is linked to? These subscriptions are linked to one Azure AD account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at has nothing to do with what Azure resources you can and cannot deploy to -- this is just for Azure AD connectivity and for billing purposes.

You set up your Azure subscriptions for continuous delivery by creating [Service Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts) in VSTS.

Comment: Service Endpoint documentation helped me a treat thanks Daniel.